# How to access a variable on all page?

Tags: variables, options

I added a variable to my functions.php file:

```
$options = get_option( 'simple_options' );
```

I can access to this variable on every page, but If I call it in the footer.php it's not working. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you cannot access local variables in a function from outside the function, so this...

```
function func() {
    $var = 2;
}

$var = 1;
func();
echo $var;
```

would result in "1".

To make a global variable, you can do this to make `$option` available outside `functions.php`:

```
function func() {
    global $option;
    $option = get_option( 'simple_options' );
}
```

However, I cannot recommend it, since every other script may change the value. You can use a define:

```
define('MY_OPTION',get_option( 'simple_options' );
```

And in your footer:

```
echo MY_OPTION; // note that there are no quotation marks
```

But also this wouldn't be that neat, since you'd have to make sure no other script defines this `MY_OPTION` and you cannot change it later on.

**No, your best bet is to get the option just again in your footer.**